# NHibernate Many-to-many

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I have a legacy database and I am trying to create a NHibernate DAL.
I have a problem with a mapping on Many-To-Many table.

The Database tables:

- `studio_Subscribers`
- `studio_Groups` (contains a IList of Subscribers)
- `studio_Subscribers_Groups` - Many-To-Many table with primary keys

The problem is when I create a `SubscriberGroup` instance and fill it with Subscribers they gets saved to the `studio_Subscribers` table but not to the Many-To-Many table.

I cant figure out whats wrong?

`studio_Subscribers` table mapping:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    assembly="Meridix.Studio.Common"
    namespace="Meridix.Studio.Common">
    <class name="SubscriberItem" table="studio_Subscribers">
        <id name="StorageId" column="Id" unsaved-value="0" access="nosetter.camelcase">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="Id" column="DomainId" not-null="true" />
        <property name="Subscriber" column="Subscriber" not-null="true" length="50" />
        <property name="Description" column="Description" not-null="false" length="100" />
        <property name="Type" column="Type" not-null="true" length="40" 
            type="Meridix.Studio.Data.Repositories.EnumStringTypes.SubscriberTypeEst, Meridix.Studio.Data.Repositories" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

`studio_Groups` table mapping:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    assembly="Meridix.Studio.Common"
    namespace="Meridix.Studio.Common">
    <class name="SubscriberGroup" table="studio_Groups">
        <id name="StorageId" column="Id" unsaved-value="0" access="nosetter.camelcase">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="Id" column="DomainId" not-null="true" />
        <property name="Name" column="Name" not-null="true" length="200" />
        <property name="Description" column="Description" not-null="false" length="300" />

        <bag name="Subscribers" table="studio_Groups_Subscribers" access="nosetter.camelcase">
            <key column="GroupId"></key>
            <many-to-many column="SubscriberId" class="SubscriberItem" />
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you have an appropriate bag on your subscriber aswell with a many-to-many relation to the group?

```
<bag name="Groups" table="studio_Groups_Subscribers" access="nosetter.camelcase">
        <key column="SubscriberId"></key>
        <many-to-many column="GroupId" class="GroupItem" />
</bag>
```

and maybe have a  cascade="save-update" on your SubscriberItems collection so that saving the Group will update your children with the appropriate relation from "the other side".

Comment: jishi: You saved me. thanks. To the rest: Make sure you have both classes referencing each other, define the two bags on each side (make sure one is inverse, one is not). And don't forget to set the references during runtinme: a.bList.Add(b); b.aList.Add(a);

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is to do with the cascade options, check out Ayende's post on it and I imagine with a bit of Googling you can find the correct syntax to go into your hbm file. I use fluent-NHibernate so I can't help you with the XML file.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/02/NHibernateCascadesTheDifferentBetweenAllAlldeleteorphansAndSaveupdate.aspx