# Nhibernate design and composite keys

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Ok I'm in a situation where I have the following tables

User (UserId ....)
UserFavourite (UserId, OtherUserId, AddDate)

If you "favourite" another user it adds a row into userFavourite. Now I have referential integrity between both UserId and OtherUserId columns and the User table with two foreign key constraints.

My question is, what is the best practice for accessing this through NHibernate? The basic Get<> method takes an id, which is the ID column. In this case the unique identifying characteristic of the table is a composite key of UserId and OtherUserId, so this leads me to think I should have a composite key. I read everywhere that they are bad though and if the DB is designed right I shouldnt be using them.

So I thought of how else I could design the DB, and I suppose I could have

UserFavourite (UniqueID, UserId, OtherUserId, AddDate)

And make UniqueId the PK and ID for the Get method, and put a unique constraint on the UserId/OtherUserId columns. However this does not solve my problem, as when I want to delete the row through code or get it, I still need to pass the UniqueID, which I will not have access to. I want to be able to say

"Remove this user (User Id 142) from your favourites". So I only have access to the UserId, and your own UserId, so somehow I need to be able to run an NHibernate query using those two ID's, not the unique ID.

Can someone point me in the direction of how this case should be handled in NHibernate via ideal practises so that I can easily and efficiently do these queries without using composite keys?

Answer (score 0):

For a pure relationship table, you could have gone for a many-to-many mapping (see [NHibernate Many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/317154/1236044) )

Considering your relationship table holds data as the AddDate (maybe more later), I think you should go for a UniqueID, then have collection mappings

- two one-to-many with inverse="true" from your User class to the UserFavourite class.
- two many-to-one from your UserFavourite class to the user class

You'll probably never use the UniqueId for deleting UserFavourite. You'll just filter the desired UserFavourite among the UserFavourites of your current User, and delete it.

Maybe you won't use the AddDate frequently. I guess that with the correct mapping attributes relative to updates (cascade, save, update, delete) you can combine the two methods (many-to-many + relationship mappings).

Comment: Im a bit confused about the two one-to-many mappings on the user class, would you be able to post an example mapping with this? Im not sure how you both declare the UserId property and have two separate mappings in the file for that same property. Also when you say I'll probably never use the UniqueId for deleting, how do I delete otherwise? I thought the only way to delete using the session object was with the ID?